# "attempt to compare string with number" ao fazer comparação em Lua

Tags: lua

```
print("Qual é a sua idade")
idade = io.read()

if idade < 18 then
   print("Você é menor de idade")
else
  print("Você é maior de idade")
end
```

Ele sempre dá esse erro :

```
lua: aula05_parte4.lua:4: attempt to compare string with number
stack traceback:
aula05_parte4.lua:4: in main chunk
[C]: in ?
```

O que eu posso fazer?

Comment: faltou `idade = tonumber(idade)`

Comment: Ok, vou testar :)

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado !!!

Answer (score 6):

O método `io.read()` retorna uma `string` (cadeia de caracteres).

Você está comparando essa string com o número 18. Não pode misturar os dois tipos (string com número) nas comparações.

Para converter uma `string` em número existe a função `tonumber(string)`.

Exemplo de uso:

```
print("Qual é a sua idade")
idadetexto = io.read()

idadenumero = tonumber(idadetexto)

if idadenumero < 18 then
  print("Você é menor de idade")
else
  print("Você é maior de idade")
end
```

Note que poderia ter feito simplesmente `idade = tonumber(idade)`, mas preferi usar variáveis de nomes diferentes para facilitar a visualização.

Conforme observação do colega @Francisco nos comments, vale notar que se o `tonumber` não conseguir a conversão, retorna `nil` (que é o valor nulo, e não uma string `"nil"`). Pode ser necessário testar o retorno dependendo da aplicação.

Para testar se retornou um `nil` você usa `if variavel == nil`, sem aspas.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado :)

Comment: importante lembrar que o tonumber retorna nil caso não consiga converter o input

Comment: @Francisco adicionei sua observação.